# How to open new ppt document

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office

i have already opened PPT Document in my system,just i open new PPT document from c#(WPF)
Exception thrown,Here's the relevant text from the log file:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80080005

using given code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
```

Windows 7 professional, 64 bit
Office 2007, all components installed it.

How can I handle this?

I need any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest to use something like NPOI, instead of Office COM automation.

Comment: using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint 12.0 object dll.

Comment: Have you installed the Office PIAs?

Comment: FYI, the above refers to Primary Interop Assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but change it to  Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint:

```
string[] SplitHTML = fileName.Split('.');
string NameNoExt = SplitHTML[0];
string FileAsHtml = NameNoExt + ".html";

//Word with the document
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(uri);
_doc.SaveAs2(FileAsHtml, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);
_doc.Close(false);
wordApp.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_doc);
browser.Navigate(FileAsHtml);
```